# An 1980s or early 90s cartoon about a girl's doll that came to life and had limited magic powers

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic, cartoon, magical-items

This is a vague memory, but I seem to recall a TV pilot, based on a toy doll that was in existence at that time, but for the life of me, I *cannot* remember either the doll or this one-time show.  This was most likely between 1988 and 1991.

A girl and her father are on a cruise with her doll, when somehow, the doll ends up overboard. There is a strike of lightning, a bell sound, and the doll opens her eyes. In-story it seemed that the lightning strike was the source of the doll's power.  The doll was somehow returned to the girl, who later finds out it (a blond haired, blue eyed baby girl effigy) is "alive" and can speak to her.

More than that, the doll has limited magical powers:  I **specifically** remember her and the girl getting on the bus, and the doll using her magic to take control of the vehicle. I believe there was some kind of adventure component to the show, but I was young, it was seemingly girly, and I wasn't that interested. I only wanted to keep note of it because my little cousin had said she wanted a black version of that doll, and her birthday was coming up.

Does anybody remember this show, or at least the exact toy it was based on?

I'm fairly certain it didn't go beyond the pilot, because I never saw it again.

Comment: Can you specify when (in which year) you saw that on TV ?

Comment: @DavidW Yes. Please pardon me; been working all weekend, so somewhat out of it. But yes, the doll was accidentally tossed overboard during the storm. And the onl reason I remember the storm was due to the lightning, which _seemed_ to be the "cause" of her animation and magical powers.

Comment: @Manuki Honestly...between 1988 and 1991 is _probably_ the **most** accurate I can be. I was a kid when I saw this, and only half paying attention; it was only because it was linked to a toy my cousin _so_ desperately wanted that it stuck out as it did. Between the ages of 8 and 10 (the time Tasha and I were closest) is really the best I can supply for you. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be a Julie Doll, a talking interactive doll that [Worlds of Wonder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worlds_of_Wonder_(toy_company)) introduced in 1987, the same year they also came up with the cartoon special you're looking for: [***Meet Julie***](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0305817/).

Everything you mentioned (her falling off a ship then getting struck by lightning and coming alive, her turning into a blonde girl & her controlling a bus with her magic powers) is there. The entire thing is currently available on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ebSVrzeyZ8), and here's the intro:

Comment: Thank you! I knew this wasn't a fever dream, and it was driving me absolutely **nuts** ; had a *nighhtmare* about this thing! Appreciate it, Walt.

Comment: @RussRainford No problem! Glad you found it. Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark, thereby resolving the issue for good. ;)